# How can I get a regular expression to match files ending in ".js" but not ".test.js"?

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I am using webpack which takes regular expressions to feed files into loaders. I want to exclude test files from build, and the test files end with `.test.js`. So, I am looking for a regular expression that would match `index.js` but not `index.test.js`.

I tried to use a negative lookback assertion with

```
/(?<!\.test)\.js$/
```

but it says that the expression is invalid.

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!\.test)\.js$/: Invalid group
```

example files names:

```
index.js          // <-- should match
index.test.js     // <-- should not match
component.js      // <-- should match
component.test.js // <-- should not match
```

Comment: Not looked at webpack in a long time but I seem to remember that you can skip the regular expression and pass a function instead. Something like this in your case: `function (path) { return path.endsWith('.js') && !path.endsWith('test.js')}` I could be mixing this up with some other bundler though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var re=/^(?!.*test\.js).*\.js$/;
console.log(re.test("index.test.js"));
console.log(re.test("test.js"));
console.log(re.test("someother.js"));
console.log(re.test("testt.js"));
```

Answer (score 7):

There you go:

```
^(?!.*\.test\.js$).*\.js$
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2X2MZT/1).

---

*As mentioned by others, the regex engine used by JavaScript does not support all features. For example, **negative lookbehinds** are not supported.*

Comment: My bad for disrupting your answer again, this is actually the best regex presented (ie the only one to have the end-of-line positional in the lookahead to not catch mid-string test.js )

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't support negative lookbehinds, but lookarounds:

```
^((?!\.test\.).)*\.js$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/m0Ottn/1)